# Arm assembly / How to fix Termite display problem?

Tags: assembly, arm, display, keil, baud-rate

I am using Keil UVision 5 and TM4C123GXL Development Board. It has cortex m4 MCU on it. To display my outputs and enter inputs I use Termite. However, sometimes it displays weird stuff as shown below. When I try reset and run again, It sometimes prints correct. How could I fix this problem?
Thanks.
[image: Termite Display Error]

Comment: You haven't shown us the code you use for reproducing this behavior, which makes it impossible for us to rule out that you have a bug in your code.

Comment: It is not related with the code. I don't get this error on my other pc. The problem is related to Baud Rate but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This means your Baud rate is incorrect, I'm not sure about your exact board but most TM4C boards use a baud rate of 115200.